# Getting Cloud9 (Ubuntu 14.04) running with PHP 7.0 and phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using Cloud9 (running Ubuntu 14.04). I've been able to remove PHP5 and update to PHP 7.0.2 (phpinfo shows accurately). However the removal of PHP5 also removes phpMyAdmin.

When trying to install PHPMyAdmin I get the following errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-cli php-seclib php-gettext
....
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-gettext : Depends: php5 but it is not going to be installed or
                        php5-cli but it is not going to be installed
 php-seclib : Depends: php5 but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-cli but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: php5-mcrypt but it is not going to be installed or
                          php5-gmp but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've added and updated my repositories. I've tried to install php5-gettext and php-seclib but again it relies on PHP5. The latest version of phpMyAdmin (4.5.3.1) is compatible with PHP5 and PHP7.

Some threads indicate to install manually form phpmyadmin.com but I don't know how to do this :(

I'm looking for a solid method to upgrade my Cloud9 workspace to PHP 7 with phpMyAdmin. All I need is phpMyAdmin currently.

Comment: Download [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) and [install it manually](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install)?

Comment: I am very green to Linux/Ubuntu and have no idea how to do this :(

Comment: The linked documentation has detailed instructions. Every answer here would be exactly what's described there.

Comment: Manual install doesn't seem to work for cloud 9. I downloaded it to my workspace but when I run the server you can't access /phpmyadmin/. I've tried unzipping to /workspace/phpmyadmin2/ and can create the config file but it doesn't seem to apply. When I try to login to localhost/phpmyadmin2/ it doesn't accept any login/password combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working.. Here is full instructions for PHP 7 + phpMyAdmin

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y purge php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-imap php5-intl php5-json php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-pspell php5-readline php5-sqlite
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install php7.0
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
mysql-ctl start

# **REMEMBER What cloud9 user name you are. This is your mysql username.
sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
```

Download phpmyadmin latest from phpmyadmin.net, extract and update contents to c9 workspace. I uploaded to ~/workspace/my/.

Create /my/config/ directory

```
Run site /my/setup/

Created new server with:
Server name: localhost
Connection type: tcp
Connect without password: on
User for config auth: none
Password for config auth: none
Allow logins without a password: on
Control user: **your c9 username**
Control pass: none
```

Click the "SAVE" button. Copy the config.inc.php file out of ~/workspace/my/config/ into ~/workspace/my/ and delete the config folder.

Restart your apache/mysql services and connect to http://localhost/my/